# Jquery hover with .on()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

Im trying to use hover with .on(), but all bits of code and answers i find do not work.

I need to use .on because its Ajax content.

A few ive tried:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[rel=popup]', function() {
    mouseMove = true;
    width = 415;
    $('#tool-tip').show();

    var type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        id = $(this).attr('data-skillid');

    console.log("TT-open");
    ttAjax(type, id);
}).on('mouseleave', '[rel=popup]', function() {
    mouseMove = false;
    console.log("TT-close");
    $('#tool-tip').hide();
    $('#tt-cont').html("");
    $('#tt-ajax').show();
});

$('[rel=popup]').on('hover',function(e) { 
    if(e.type == "mouseenter") {
        mouseMove = true;
        width = 415;
        $('#tool-tip').show();

        var type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
            id = $(this).attr('data-skillid');

        console.log("TT-open");
        ttAjax(type, id);
    }
    else if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
        mouseMove = false;
        console.log("TT-close");
        $('#tool-tip').hide();
        $('#tt-cont').html("");
        $('#tt-ajax').show();
    }
});

$('[rel=popup]').on("hover", function(e) {

    if (e.type === "mouseenter") { console.log("enter"); }
    else if (e.type === "mouseleave") { console.log("leave"); }

});

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        console.log("on");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        console.log("off");
    }
}, "[rel=popup]"); //pass the element as an argument to .on
```

The original non .on:

```
$('[rel=popup]').hover(function(){
    mouseMove = true;
    width = 415;
    $('#tool-tip').show();

    var type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        id = $(this).attr('data-skillid');

    console.log("TT-open");
    ttAjax(type, id);

},function () {
    mouseMove = false;
    console.log("TT-close");
    $('#tool-tip').hide();
    $('#tt-cont').html("");
    $('#tt-ajax').show();
})
```

All the .on return "TypeError: $(...).on is not a function". I am using version 1.9.1.

Comment: "hover" is not an event.

Comment: i also use mouseeneter and leave, they also do not work.

Comment: If you're getting that error, you're either not really using the version of jQuery that you think you are, or else there's a `$` conflict.

Comment: Look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/eGn3M/ It works just fine. Definitely try using `jQuery` instead of `$`.

Comment: I agree with @Pointy, you must not be using 1.91. In your console type: `$.fn.jquery`, what # comes up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The events you're looking for may be

```
$("#id").mouseover(function(){});
```

or

```
$("#id").mouseout(function(){});
```

Comment: The "mouseenter" and "mouseleave" events are managed by jQuery and should work fine.

Comment: Despite the comment above and the downvote, this isn't a bad suggestion as it works from jQuery 1.0+ and the questioner's problem seems to be that he's not using the version he thinks (or there's a conflict between versions.)  But I would really recommend fixing the version issue and doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

There was an answer with:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        console.log("on");
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        console.log("off");
    }
},"[rel=popup]");
```

This worked, and for some reason I have JQ 1.4 in a 1.9.1 named file that was causing the problem.

Comment: So a bad script file was the problem - nothing to do with your code.